# How to truncate UTF8 string in JavaScript without breaking multibyte characters?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, utf-8, truncation

My apologies if this has been answered here already. I couldn't find a relevant thread.

I'm brand new at JavaScript. I need to be able to truncate a string in a UTF8-friendly way. Currently, using `slice()` and similar methods, multibyte characters at the end of the string are chopped in half and I get invalid characters.

```js
//Slicing Emojis
var emojitext = "";
var chopped_emoji = emojitext.slice(0, 1);
document.getElementById("slice").innerHTML = chopped_emoji + " is broken";
```

```html
<p id="slice"></p>
```

The above code results in an invalid character stored in `chopped_emoji`. How do I make sure this does not happen?

Comment: try `var chopped_emoji = emojitext.slice(0, 2);`

Answer (score 4):

JS has a new [segmentation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter) for working with string characters. Depending on the [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter#browser_compatibility) you need, it could be a good fit (you could also polyfill it). You can use it to create an array of graphemes (ie: the visually perceived letters/units on the screen). You can then use `.slice()` on that array and then `.join()` it back into a string:

```js
const str = "";

const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter("en", {granularity: 'grapheme'});
const segItr = segmenter.segment(str);
const segArr = Array.from(segItr, ({segment}) => segment);
const choppedEmoji = segArr.slice(0, 1).join('');

// Examples
console.log("With segmentation", choppedEmoji);
console.log("Without segmentation", str.slice(0, 1));
```

The above deals with a lot of edge cases such as surrogate pairs (emojis such as ), characters with zero-width joiners (for emojis such as ‍‍), characters with variation selectors (such as ❤️) and composite pair characters (such as `ñ`).

For simpler characters, you can use `Array.from()` or the spread syntax (`...`) to convert your string into an array grouped by the *code points* of your string (an emoji can consist of multiple code units that encode a single code point), this way when you split, you can avoid splitting on one of the code units (which causes the error character):

```js
const emojitext = "";
const choppedEmoji = [...emojitext].slice(0, 1).join('');
console.log(choppedEmoji + " is not broken :)");
```

But if you throw something like `‍‍` into the above example though, you'll find that it doesn't work as expected, as `‍‍` is a grapheme that consists of multiple code points joined by zero-width joiner characters, so the above approach won't work with it, but the segmenter option will (same thing with characters consisting of variation selectors and composite characters).